# When to use Log-polar transformation on images

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I was reading in my textbook (about image processing with c++) and stumbled over, when or in what application to use a log-polar transformation on images? (so in other words, when will it be effective to apply)

Answer (score 0):

One application that comes to mind is in robotics. Football robots most probably use log-polar transformations to convert their 360 degrees camera image (a camera pointed at a special mirror) to a rectangular (cartesian) image for analysis. This way they can "see" their opponents. There are also applications in medical imaging and more.

Eindhoven Technical University uses such an approach, like many others.

https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12080466_837871286332706_1647413204_n.jpg